# RSelenium + RTools42 issue cannot open the connection: no such file or directory

Tags: r, rselenium, rtools

Trying to use RSelenium and firefox to interact with a website but keep bonking on no such path or directory for the zip file despite other temp files getting added to the same folder.

None of the other discussions of the issue have fixed it. Tried reinstalling rtools42 tried adding it to the PATH environmental variable

Here's the code I'm using that works for two colleagues on the same network:

```
firefoxProfile <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "application/comma-seperated-values, text/csv, text/plain, application/zip, application/octet-stream"))
```

Here's the error message only I get:

```
Error in file(tmpfile, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(tmpfile, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\file\filename.zip': No such file or directory
```

Baffled

Comment: What is your version of R?

Comment: 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library Book"

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled a few times then reinstalled and installed Rcpp as mentioned in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBTObNFFkhs

Still a bit mysterious to me why getting Rcpp fixed it given that my colleagues didn't have to do this but this did solve it for me.